# Tanya's description of Divine assistance to benoni and freedom of choice

Tags: free-will-bechira, tanya

In Likutei Amarim Chapter 13, the Tanya says ([quoted here](https://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/tanya.asp?tdate=1/11/2023), with explanations interpolated)

> Yet, inasmuch as the evil in the left part of the beinoni’s heart is in its native strength, craving after all the pleasures of this world, and is neither so minute as to be nullified before the good of the divine soul (as is the case with a tzaddik), nor has it been displaced from its position to any degree, but merely lacks authority and power to become diffused throughout the limbs of the body to cause them to do, speak, or think evil, **nor is the evil’s lack of ability attributable to the beinoni’s efforts**, for his evil, like that of the rasha, retains its native strength to pervade the entire body; rather, the evil is powerless merely because of the Holy One, blessed be He, who “stands at the right hand of the poor man,” helping him and irradiating his divine soul so that it may be able to prevail over the evil.

The bolded (emphasis mine) line (which is actually not a direct translation but an interpretation) seems to say that the person's own efforts play no role in the fact that he doesn't sin. For if his efforts did play a role (even if partial, together with G-d's help), the evil's lack of ability *would be* attributable to those efforts.

Put differently, if not sinning is truly not attributable to his efforts, then it shouldn't matter if he stops making any effort at all - it shouldn't change the outcome! (For if stopping the efforts does change the outcome, then clearly the efforts have a causal effect, and thus the result *is* attributable [in part] to them).

But if his efforts don't change the outcome - i.e. he doesn't sin whether he puts in the effort or not - then this person doesn't have any free choice, in the sense that his different choices don't actually result in any different outcomes, and hence are irrelevant/don't matter.

Comment: For the record, the bolded parts (in the linked text) are direct translations. The part you highlighted is interpretation, and it could be better phrased IMO. I think it's trying to explain why the good inclination gets the final say if they're both on equal footing in a beinuni. It's not that the beinuni's efforts are in vain, but that they wouldn't always be _sufficient_ without Hashen weighing in on the side of good.

Comment: right, I've edited my post to note that the bolded part in my question is an interpretation.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure the correlation between effort and choice is valid. The tzaddik (as defined in Tanya) effortlessly abstains from sinning, but still has the freedom to choose differently, perhaps in the way we effortlessly abstain from murder or suicide, despite our ability to act otherwise if we chose to.

Comment: While choice doesn’t always require effort (as in your example), an effort is always undertaken by choice. So it is valid to say that if it’s the case that a benoni’s efforts don’t matter then the choices behind those efforts  also don’t matter.

Comment: See footnote 4 on chapter 13 (Lessons in Tanya) - https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7892/jewish/Chapter-13.htm#footnoteRef4a7892

Comment: 1) I have a physical copy of Practical Tanya, by Rabbi Chaim Miller. In it (p. 155) he explains this as follow: in chapter 12, it is explained that the brain's will-power is enough and completely devoted to overcome the Yetzer Hara. However, this is the case of contemplative prayer. In the case of chapter 13, this is not true. In this case, the beinoni is in the unenlightened state, devoid of the residual effects of contemplative prayer. Hence, the Yetzer Hara is able to rise. The brain is thus confused by "two voices" so to speak.

Comment: 2) And thus, the Alter Rebbe explains that G-d stands on the right. This can be found in the Gemara (Kiddushin 30b), where it is explained: And if not for the fact that the Holy One, Blessed be He, assists each person in battling his evil inclination, he could not overcome it.

Comment: @Shmuel maybe I haven't read the question properly, but this sounds like a very good answer to the question

Comment: @Shmuel I’m not sure how this answers the question. The question was specifically about the use of the words ‘not attributable’ when talking about a person’s role in avoiding sin, and that such phrasing implies there’s no free choice.

Comment: @user9806 this is the way Rabbi Miller explains this Tanya.